# Java Paint() issues

Tags: java

first post here ever so forgive me if I am totally ignorant of all the rules.

I have some issues, I am relatively new to Java and have read and got some help from this community before.

I am having issues at the moment paint multiple balls on a JFrame, I have some solutions from other students but to no success. One student has got it working now but by painting everything within the Frame class which I don't feel is correct and putting repaint() within paint() which also feels wrong. if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be extremely appreciative.

Daniel

Code:
**Gamejava**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package myanimie;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Dan
 */
public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable {


    private Ball myBall = new Ball();
    private Paddle myPad = new Paddle();
    final JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    final JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    final JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();



    public Game()
    {
        setVisible(true);        
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("First Test Animation");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setSize(640,480);


    }

public void run()
    {
    move();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        myBall.paint(g);
    }

    public void move()
    {

      myBall.start();
      repaint();

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    }
```

**Ball.java**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package myanimie;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

/**
 *
 * @author Dan
 */
public class Ball  extends Thread  {

    Point pos;
    Color ballColor = Color.red;
    Color[] ts = {Color.CYAN,Color.green,Color.black};
    private int yChange = 2;
    private int xChange = 1;



    public Ball()
    {
    pos = new Point();
    pos.x = (int)(Math.random() * (500 - 100)) + 10 ;
    pos.y = (int)(Math.random() * (500/2 - 100)) + 10;

    }




    @Override
    public void run()
    {
     while(true)
    {
       move();

    }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
       g.setColor(ballColor);
       g.fillOval(pos.x - 10, pos.y - 10, 60,60);     

    }


    public void move()
    {
//        System.out.println("y " + pos.y);
//        System.out.println("x " + pos.x);

        if(pos.y < 20)
        {            
            yChange = -yChange;            
            System.out.println("T");
            ballColor = Color.BLUE;
        }
        if(pos.x < 20)
        {
            xChange = -xChange;
            System.out.println("L");
            ballColor = Color.MAGENTA;
        }
        if(pos.x > 620 - 20)
        {
        xChange = -xChange;
        System.out.println("R");
        ballColor = Color.GREEN;
        }
        if(pos.y > 430 - 20)
        {
            yChange = -yChange;
            System.out.println("B");
            ballColor = Color.PINK;
        }
        if(pos.y < 640 - 20)
        {
            pos.translate(xChange, yChange);           
        }
        if(pos.x < 480 - 20 || pos.x > 460)
        {
            pos.translate(xChange, yChange);           
        }   
        }


    public Point getPosition()
    {
        return pos;
    }



    public Ellipse2D area()
    {
        return new Ellipse2D.Double(pos.x, pos.y,60,60);
    }

    }
```

This is my terrible code, I have gotten around the errors but no animation atm.

Thanks guys!! your insight is invaluable

Comment: Whats the issue? Where's the misbehaving code?

Comment: Remove the call to `repaint()` in `Game` class' `move` method. It will not do what you expect it to do. The update to graphics would happen via paint() that you are calling in `Ball` class. Also, you need to check the way you are getting x and y for your move() you may not be getting values that will cause any movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK some general observations based on the code you posted.

1. You need to throttle your `move()` method so that it's not updating millions of times per second.  I see you have a `Thread.sleep()` in your `Game.move` method.  I think what you were trying to do was something like this:

   ```
   public void run() {
       while(true) {
           //change the game state
           move();

           //draw the changes to the state that I just made
           repaint();

           //wait before moving to the next "frame"
           try {
              Thread.sleep(50);
           } catch ( InterruptedException ie ) {
           }
       }
   }

   private void move() {
       myBall.move();
   }
   ```
2. Since `Ball.move()` won't loop anymore, don't have `Ball` extend `Thread` at all.  Get rid of the `run()` method.  Your main game loop will be managed centrally by `Game`.
3. From your `main` method or whoever starts the game running, call `Game.run()` either in that thread or in a new thread like this:

   ```
     public void main(String[] args) {
         Game game /* = new Game(...)*/;
         Thread gameThread = new Thread(game);
         gameThread.start();
     }
   ```
4. Is there a good reason for `getPosition()` to exist?  This is probably better off as [encapsulated state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Comment: Thanks alot Mark, I did have that situation working before but as I am currently learning about threads I wanted to get each Ball in a separate thread and painting on the screen, I actually have it working now albeit really messy:     public void move()
    {
      myBall.start();
      while(true)
      {
      repaint();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    }   So I think after reading about threads an not actually implementing them in Swing I should not do this

Comment: @Daniel You might want to look at Swing Timers if you just want to refresh the screen every Xms. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html. I agree with avoiding all of the extra threads.

Comment: One thing I didn't mention for the sake of simplicity is that there *could* be a race condition between `move()` and `paint()`.  It's overwhelmingly unlikely since we are sleeping for a long time, but please don't take this as a "perfect" solution.

Comment: @Daniel: I see a lot of people try the same "multi-agent" approach as you took.  It seems promising, keeping all of the logic in one execution unit.  But in reality it almost always causes crippling complexity in the code...particularly when two of these objects all of a sudden need to interact!

Comment: Thanks for all the help! and to you Mark, I have alot to learn :) I think in essence I will revert back to having everything in the same thread to reduce the overall complexity

Answer (score 1):

"and putting repaint() within paint()" sounds dangerous!

`repaint()`  method causes a call to this component's paint method as soon as possible. 
You may elaborate how you are trying to draw "multiple" balls on the frame. If nothing special, your answer may be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023236/drawing-multiple-circles-with-java2d)

Comment: `repaint` posts to the EDT though -- as it is it won't cause infinite recursion but is a rather silly hack to "repaint again as soon as possible" which, among other things, may repaint too many times and waste resources (namely it may needlessly increase CPU usage).

Comment: Thanks ring bearer! Basically I can create and add multiple balls to the JFrame just by creating a new ball and then painting it on the JFrame, I wanted to put each ball in its own thread and thats when I started having all the troubles. I will have a read of the other post now thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Threading *does not* play well with Swing. Namely, all operations using Swing should be on the EDT. The `paint` method (queued via `repaint`) executes in the context of the EDT thread (as it is put in the dispatch queue and then run from the EDT) ... other threads be warned.

Comment: @pst: `repaint()` can be called from any thread.  It is `paint()`, `update()`, etc that need to be called from the event thread (and will be if called indirectly via `repaint()`.

Comment: @Mark Peters With Swing I always err on the side of caution when it comes to threads. Lol. Update around each-other -- you're correct though, my previous (version of) comment slightly erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is indeed very bad practice. Calling `repaint()` in `paint()` will cause a [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) Error.
Take a look at the game engine [Bonsai](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/Bonsai-Game-Library) from [Ivo Wetzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170224/ivo-wetzel). I like it a lot.

And indeed: You should create a JComponent which overrides the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. Add that JComponent to the JFrame. But you don't have to care about this. This will do the Bonsai game engine automatically.

Comment: It shouldn't cause a stack overflow, it will just spam the EDT with paint requests.

Comment: I think my main problem is that I call from Game myBall.start(); this then loops but doesnt repaint properly, this is where I am coming stuck at the moment